# Adjust CommandBarButton of Fluent UI

Tags: css, css-selectors, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I would like to adjust a little bit CommandBarButton of Fluent UI. I want to move the icon a little down by adding a padding on top of it. I try to add `padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px` inside `.icon-112` in DevTools. It is perfect.

[image]

So I add the following in CSS:

```
.move .ms-Button-Icon {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; /* 10px to make it obvious */
}
```

And use `move` in

```
<CommandBarButton
  className="move"
  iconProps={{ iconName: "Comment" }}
  text="Comment"
/>
```

But it does not work; we don't see the extra padding anywhere. Does anyone know why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-glade-qu8g29?file=/src/App.js:200-314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.move .ms-Button-icon {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; /* 10px to make it obvious */
}
```

It's `.ms-Button-icon` not `.ms-Button-Icon` lol

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, this is the CSS-in-JS way preferred by Fluent UI, without using the classnames directly:

```
<CommandBarButton
  iconProps={{ iconName: "Comment" }}
  text="Comment"
  styles={{ icon: { paddingTop: 10 } }}
/>
```

Adjusted sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sunset-6ijgqf?file=/src/App.js